# Json para List C#

Tags: c#, json, array, arraylist

Tenho esse Json 
(Json 1)

```
{
    "2": {
        "Data": "28/10/2019 12:50:26",
        "Id": 2,
        "Id_usuario": 0,
        "Latitude": -2,
        "Longitude": -52,
        "Portas": 8,
        "Status": "CHEIO"
    },
    "5": {
        "Data": "28/10/2019 12:39:33",
        "Id": 5,
        "Id_usuario": 0,
        "Latitude": -2,
        "Longitude": -66,
        "Portas": 8,
        "Status": "lIVRE"
    }
}
```

Percebi que meu codigo consegue ler nesta formatação
(Json 2)

```
[
  {
    "Data": "28/10/2019 12:50:26",
    "Id": 2,
    "Id_usuario": 0,
    "Latitude": -2,
    "Longitude": -52,
    "Portas": 8,
    "Status": "CHEIO"
  },
  {
    "Data": "28/10/2019 12:39:33",
    "Id": 5,
    "Id_usuario": 0,
    "Latitude": -2,
    "Longitude": -66,
    "Portas": 8,
    "Status": "lIVRE"
  }
]
```

Mas do firebase o Json vem no formato do primeiro código (Json 1)
Já tentei usar

```
List<Item_Caixa> caixas;

FirebaseResponse response = firebaseClient.Get(path);
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
caixas = js.Deserialize<List<Item_Caixa>>(response.Body);// não funciona

caixas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item_Caixa>>(response.Body);// não funciona
```

Minha Classe

```
public class Item_Caixa
{
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public int portas { get; set; }
        public double latitude { get; set; }
        public double longitude { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set; }
        public int id_usuario { get; set; }
}
```

Já olhei várias perguntas como esta aqui no StackOverflow mas nenhuma das respostas ta dando certo.
O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Acredito que se você utilizar os nomes das variáveis do json identicas ao da classe Item_Caixa.

```
   [
  {
    "data": "28/10/2019 12:50:26",
    "id": 2,
    "id_usuario": 0,
    "latitude": -2,
    "longitude": -52,
    "portas": 8,
    "status": "CHEIO"
  },
  {
    "data": "28/10/2019 12:39:33",
    "id": 5,
    "id_usuario": 0,
    "latitude": -2,
    "longitude": -66,
    "portas": 8,
    "status": "lIVRE"
  }
]
```

---

Utilizando desta forma acredito que haverá um link entre os atributos, pois se você colocar para receber um tipo objective ele ira usar esses nomes como atributos, acredito que com os nomes iguais na hora do cast para Item_Caixa daria certo. Espero ter ajudado...

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta assim:

```
List<Item_Caixa> caixas;

FirebaseResponse response = firebaseClient.Get(path);
 dynamic data  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Body);

caixas = ((IDictionary<string, JToken>)data).Select(k =>
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item_Caixa>(k.Value.ToString())).ToList();
```

Comment: Funcionou. Muito obrigado